# Updated node on my system, now grunt won't run in npm project

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I recently updated node on my computer to 0.12.4. And that seems to have done something to a project I’m working inside node.js express.js. As near as I can tell there appears to be come kind of compatibility issue between the version of node I’m now running and the node_modules. I used Git to go back to previous versions of this project (versions which worked fine) and now they don’t work either.

My computer is running:
OSX Yosemite 10.10.3
node: 0.12.4
npm: 2.11.3

My project’s dependancies in my package.json file:

```
    "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
      "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
      "debug": "~2.0.0",
      "express": "~4.9.0",
      "grunt": "^0.4.5",
      "grunt-sass": "^0.17.0",
      "jade": "~1.6.0",
      "morgan": "~1.3.0",
      "node-sass": "^1.2.3",
      "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
    }
```

The problem: When I run `grunt` in the terminal I get errors telling me:

```
    Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

So I removed all the node_modules and ran `npm install` in the terminal and I get more errors:

```
    Error: Module did not self-register.
      at Error (native)
      at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
      at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
      at require (module.js:384:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sheynawatkins/dev/node/lola/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:181:15)
      at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
    npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.4
    npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! node-sass@1.2.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@1.2.3 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an ancient version of `node-sass` (^1.2.3, while the current version is 3.2.0), so try installing a more recent version (which installs just fine for me with Node 0.12):

```
$ npm i node-sass@latest --save
```

Comment: Yes, that's what the problem was. After I did that I also had to update grunt-sass and now grunt will run properly. Thank you!